# Why does loading libsodium.pyd succeeds in python.exe, but fails in embedded Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ctypes

In Windows 8 I have a QGIS installation ["Standalone installer Version 2.10 (64 bit)"](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html). I try to get an IPython kernel from QGIS's embedded Python, and installed some packages with pip. `import IPython` gives no error. `IPython.start_kernel()` gives no error, when I call it from python.exe in the OSGeo4W shell as non-administrator. But when I do the same in the QGIS Python console, I get a stacktrace.

The error happens when loading libsodium.pyd, which is demonstrated below. I cared to have the same working directory and PATH environment variable.

What else can make the difference?

python.exe session from the OSGeo4W shell:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, os, ctypes
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\bin\\python.exe'
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\bin'
>>> for x in os.environ['PATH'].split(';'): print x
...
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\Scripts
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\WBem
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\msys\bin
>>> ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\zmq\\libsodium.pyd')
<CDLL 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\libsodium.pyd', handle 80000000 at 1e9e780>
```

QGIS Python console:

```
Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
import sys, os, ctypes
sys.version
'2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
sys.executable
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\bin\\qgis-bin.exe'
os.getcwd()
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\bin'
os.environ['PATH'] = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\Scripts;C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\WBem;C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\msys\\bin'
for x in os.environ['PATH'].split(';'): print x
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\Scripts
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\WBem
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\msys\bin
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISPI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\zmq\\libsodium.pyd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden
```

Comment: Have you tried typing the full path without using the `~` character? I know some packages can't handle that.

Comment: Tried again: `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Pisa\\apps\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\zmq\\libsodium.pyd')` gives the same error. Also this don't explain the different behaviour. @Monkey

Comment: libsodium.pyd depends on msvcr90.dll, which is part of the VC90.CRT assembly. When importing an extension module, Python temporarily enables an activation context for the Windows loader to be able find the CRT assembly. This should work even with embedded Python. With ctypes you'd have to create and enable this activation context manually. That said, after Python imports the module the normal way, you should be able to load it using ctypes (for whatever reason). Try `import zmq.libsodium;` `ctypes.CDLL('libsodium.pyd')`.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun. `import zmq.libsodium` has the same behaviour: works in python.exe, stacktrace "Error 126" in QGIS. I used ctype because this is what happens in `zmq.__init__.py`.

Comment: With process explorer I see: python.exe loads msvcr90.dll at startup, while msvcp90.dll is loaded with libsodium.pyd. QGIS loads both dll at startup. Path for both DLLs in both cases is `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9158_none_08e47e47a83d53d6`. I don't understand what is happening here. @eryksun

Comment: The C++ (msvcp90.dll) dependency comes from libzmq.pyd. I looked into what `zmq.__init__` is doing. Try adding the following just before the `if bundled:` block that tries to load the extension modules using ctypes: `from . import libsodium, libzmq; del libsodium, libzmq`. This will allow Python to import libsodium.pyd and libzmq.pyd the normal way before zmq tries to load them via ctypes.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you, with that change the imports work in QGIS. I still don't understand the thing with "activation context", never mind.

Comment: The above directory in "C:\Windows\WinSxS" is not on the normal DLL search path. The activation context adds this directory to the search path, per the V90.CRT assembly requirement that's in Python's manifest. Additionally it's not just about the search path; the CRT DLL refuses to load via `LoadLibrary` without this activation context (even if it's already loaded), which qgis-bin.exe lacks. Python's import system enables the saved context from when python27.dll was loaded, based on the manifest embedded in python27.dll. Thus after a normal import, using ctypes to load the modules works fine.

Comment: Yes I think this is the answer to my question. Aren't you interested in reputation points? ;-) @eryksun